# Impala null management: NULL DEFINED AS not working

Tags: null, hive, impala

I'm facing a problem with null values and Impala. I created a table like this one:

```
 create table null_test (
  id int,
  val varchar(50)
 )
 row format delimited fields terminated by ','
 null defined as 'null'
 stored as textfile
 location '/tmp/test_null'
```

and I put there a file containing

```
1,null
2,foo
3,null
```

what happens is that Hive is working as expected and it is showing me the NULL values properly, instead Impala shows as values for the id 1 and 3 the string 'null'.

Is there any way to fix this behavior from Impala? How should I say to it how NULL values are represented?

Thank you!

Comment: Try NULLIF(expr1,expr2). http://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/documentation/archive/impala/2-x/2-1-x/topics/impala_conditional_functions.html

Comment: This is a workaround as we're using now, but I'd like to know wether there is a solution to have the proper null management be done by Impala...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that Impala doesn't manage `NULL` definition different from `\N`, i.e. if you want a value to be considered as  `NULL` by Impala you have to put `\N`, regardless of any property you set.